# Browser sync in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, microsoft-edge, browser-sync

I want to use browser sync sublime text in Microsoft edge, what's the key? I used "edge","IE" both not worked

Comment: How about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74684434/browser-sync-in-sublime-text/74696962#74696962) helpful to deal with the issue? If so, you could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 2):

I test with `msedge` and it can launch Edge browser.

**browser_sync_launch.js** file:

```
var bs = require('browser-sync').create('ST3');

args = process.argv.slice(2);

bs.init({
    server:args[0],
    files:args[1].split(','),
    index:args[2],
    startPath:args[2],
    logLevel:"silent",
    browser:"msedge"
});
```

[image]